# What is the space complexity of HashTable, Array, ArrayList, LinkedList etc(if anything more)

Tags: c#, java, javascript, c++, python

I want to know the space complexities of the basic data structures in popular languages.

Comment: You should probably pick one language, and list the names in that language. C++ doesn't have any such class names in its standard library :)

Comment: Can you provide a little more explanation as to what your goal is?  Off-hand it sounds like a homework question, IMHO :)

Comment: Either restrict this to one language/framework or make the question about language-agnostic data structures.  The way it's worded right now is damn near impossible to answer reliably.

Comment: I want a community of programmers that can think about these type of problems.

Comment: well I am basically looking for the answer in java.....will be helpful if get the answer regarding time complexity of implementing , inserting an item, removing an item, etc for these data strustures.. This is not a homework question, rather keen to learn more!

Comment: People who are "keen to learn more" generally demonstrate that they have done some of their own work and research on the question before outsourcing the question to a community.

Answer (score 3):

All of these have space complexity O(n). All that changes is the coefficient, and that is completely dependent on the implementation. Especially when you start getting into things like pre-allocating space to reduce time complexity.

For instance, array list structures generally pre-allocate extra space. Therefore, their exact complexity for a number of objects is actually a range which is completely dependent on implementation and how they were created and used. For instance, if I write an array list that always allocates three extra spaces whenever more space is necessary, and always deallocates down to three open spaces when there's more than 5 open spaces, then actual complexity for n will be `[n, n + 5] + overhead`.

The big differences in choosing between these items when programming is usually ease-of-use and how well it fits with how you will be using it. For example, linked lists are horrible for random access, but great at iteration.

Answer (score 2):

For Java: (Aproximates)

```
            Memory O(x) | General Case
Array     |       n     |    n
ArrayList |       n     |    2 * n
LinkedList|       n     |    n * (node size)
HashTable |       n     |    ~n
Map       |       n     |    (n * key_size) + n
```

Comment: What the heck does 'general' mean?

Comment: @bdonlan It is my best guess for the memory use of a general implementation of the structure.

Comment: That doesn't really make much sense. For array, does n mean n bytes? If it means n items, then linkedlist is n * node size * item size bytes...?

Comment: @bdonlan I think of it as n = number of items * their size.  So, an array will take up n elements.  This isn't supposed to be an official doc...

Comment: My point is, the math is just wrong in places. LinkedList = `number of items * item size * node size` has dimensionality `byte^2`. You're not being consistent with what n means, and so the equations you give are meaningless...

Answer (score 1):

Virtually all data structures with a non-trivial size are on the ORDER of n.

- Array = exactly n
- ArrayList = betweenn and k*n (default k=2)
- LinkedList = exactly n
- HashTable = worst is n/k  (default k is .75)

Comment: Linked list is exactly n, 'ay?  Hash table requires less n space to store n elements? :)

Comment: LinkedList is exactly n. Look at the source of it. It consists of a header entry and an int for the size. Perhaps I should have mentioned the int size? And if you do the math on my HashTable, you'll see n/k, not n*k. - for example, if you have n of 1000, and k of .75, 1000/.75 = 1334, which is clearly more than 1000.

Comment: If there's a criticism to be had here, it's that ArrayList and HashTable don't shrink when you remove, so n should be interpreted as the greatest n to date for those.